# Static website on S3 with route 53 - Site can't be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have hosted a static website on S3 with suitable bucket policy set. Viewing the "endpoint" in another tab works perfectly fine. After this I created a Hosted zone in route 53 to give it a desirable human readable address.

After creating the hosted zone, I have two records in my newly created hosted zone, One being of type **NS** and the other being of type **SOA**. So far so good. I go ahead to create a new record set.

I add the **name** as desired, enter **type** as **'A' - IPv4 Address** tick yes for **Alias**, where in the drop down (**Alias Target**) i can see my previously **created bucket endpoint**.

I set the routing policy to be simple and Evaluate Health Target set to no. The record set is created successfully. However when i enter this name in another tab, I get the "Site can't be reached". I try and test the record set using the functionality provided by AWS. Here the response code i get is "NOERROR" which i assume is a positive response. Am I missing something here.

I have also referred to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4nQL5wKlEU) video. Am I missing something. Also, I have not created the Hosted Zones myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hosted zone is not the same as domain. You have to update the NS values for your domain registrar to point to the NS values as generated by Route53.

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html):

> When you create a hosted zone, Amazon Route 53 automatically creates a
>   name server (`NS`) record and a start of authority (`SOA`) record for
>   the zone. The NS record identifies the four name servers that you give
>   to your registrar or your DNS service so that DNS queries are routed
>   to Amazon Route 53 name servers.
>
> [...]
>
> After you update the settings with your domain registrar to include
>   the Amazon Route 53 name servers, Amazon Route 53 responds to DNS
>   queries for the hosted zone even if you don't have a functioning
>   website.

---

NS transfer may take from 1 to 24 hours, depending on the registrar.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I bought domain *thevegfoodies.com* through AWS Route 53, created simple index.html page and uploaded to bucket *thevegfoodies.com* and set bucket for *Static website hosting* ,added public policy. created second bucket *www.thevegfoodies.com* and redirect to *thevegfoodies.com*, created aliases everything , read through documents everything. But nothing worked.
Until, i realized that my redirect bucket *www.thevegfoodies.com* was not set for public read access. I set it too *Read bucket permissions*  for *Everyone*. (Note my primary bucket thevegfoodies.com already has public access.) and i could load my website using my domain name.

Now, I have read through AWS document again just to see if I missed this step of setting up public access for redirection bucket.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html and all other steps to setup static website.
if you check Step 2.3: Configure Your Website Redirect, it is not mention that we need to set public access.

POINT- AWS Documentation is not clear. One need to have public access to redirect bucket too.